# Number of Palindromic Slices in a string with O(N) complexity

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def solution(S):
    total = 0
    i = 1
    while i <= len(S):
        for j in range(0, len(S) - i + 1):
            if is_p(S[ j: j + i]):
                total += 1
        i += 1
    return total

def is_p(S):
    if len(S) == 1:
        return False
    elif S == S[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I am writing a function to count the number of Palindromic Slices(with length bigger than 1) in a string. The above code is in poor time complexity. Can someone help me to improve it and make it O(N) complexity?

Edit: It is not duplicate since the other question is about finding the longest Palindromic Slices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting palindromic substrings in O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647453/counting-palindromic-substrings-in-on)

Comment: It's a duplicate because, once you have the longest palindrome centered at some location, you instantly know how many (shorter) palindromes can be found centered there -- every centered substring of a palindrome is a palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

Apply [Manacher's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring#Manacher's_algorithm), also described by the [multiple answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647453/counting-palindromic-substrings-in-on).

That gives you the length of the longest palindrome centered at every location (centered at a character for odd-length, or centered between characters for even-length). You can use this to easily calculate the *number* of palindromes. Note that every palindrome must be centered *somewhere*, so it must be a substring (or equal to) the longest palindrome centered there.

So consider the string `ababcdcbaa`. By Manacher's Algorithm, you know that the maximal length palindrome centered at the `d` has length 7: `abcdcba`. By the properties of palindromes, you immediately know that `bcdcb` and `cdc` and `d` are also palindromes centered at `d`. In fact there are `floor((k+1)/2)` palindromes centered at a location, if you know that the longest palindrome centered there has length `k`.

So you sum the results of Manacher's Algorithm to get your count of all palindromes. If you want to only count palindromes of length `> 1`, you just need to subtract the number of length-1 palindromes, which is just `n`, the length of your string.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in linear time using suffix trees:

1) For constant sized alphabet we can build suffix trees using Ukkonen's Algorithm in O(n).

2) For given string S, build a generalized suffix tree of S#S'  where  S' is reverse of string S and # is delimiting character.

3) Now in this suffix tree, for every suffix i in S, look for lowest common ancestor of (2n-i+1) suffix is S'.

4) count for all such suffixes in the tree to get total count of all palindromes.

Comment: Can you write some code to accompany each step of the answer?