# How to find the longest palindrome substring by ignoring some characters

Tags: substring, character, palindrome

I searched this problem in the Google but can't find. A problem is a little bit different from the classic case:

Find the longest palindrome by ignoring some characters. For example: let's take 'abracadabra', here we can omit some characters and get "abadaba" as one of the possible longest palindrome ("ab_a__dab_a").

Can anyone suggest efficient algorithm?

Comment: I found same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577422/create-palindrome-from-existing-string-by-removing-characters).

Comment: But how to find d[i+1, j], I have no idea :(