# Finding presence of palindromic sequence in a string

Tags: string, algorithm

How do I find if a string contains a contiguous palindromic sequence ? I could try the naive solution in O(n^2) time where n is the string size , but any efficient algos to it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a function that returns the longest palindrome in a given string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115001/write-a-function-that-returns-the-longest-palindrome-in-a-given-string)

Answer (score 1):

Well looking for just any palindrome isn't particularly interesting since every one character string is a palindrome. If you are looking for the longest palindrome you may be interested in [Manacher's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring).

A good description of the algorithm can be found [here](http://leetcode.com/2011/11/longest-palindromic-substring-part-ii.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite common problem, and has ample results on google:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring

Rather than using Manacher's Algorithm you should use one of the parallel algorithms.

duplicate of : [how to find longest palindromic subsequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790522/how-to-find-longest-palindromic-subsequence)