# Algorithm to form nested pairs from a number list

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

For example, given a numbers list

sample output:
0**12**0**3**8**3****2**9**1**9
ie. 1,1  2,2 3,3 max. number is 3

How to use an algorithm to form a maxmum number of nested paris?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find longest palindromic subsequence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790522/how-to-find-longest-palindromic-subsequence)

Comment: can u guys write the answer in psedo code?

Comment: Hey Jerry I gave the link for complete code. Give me up vote man !!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Longest Palindromic Subsequence, I guess . 
O(n*n) solution is out there . Is that what you want ?
The exact procedure is =>
The problem can be solved using a recurrence relation as follows,
T(i,j) => what is the length of longest nested pair in the sub-array [i,j].
Now your answer is t(0,n-1) assume array has N elements, indexed from 0 to n-1.

T(i,j) = >
If(i>=j) T(i,j) = 0
If(arr[i] == arr[j]) T(i,j) = 2+T(i+1,j-1)
else T(i,j) = max(T(i+1,j),T(i,j-1))

Now you can either write a recursive or a bottom up DP to solve the recurrence. NOTE that while solving the recurrence you will also have to trace which Segment gave the maximum answer, and then you just need to traverse that segment and collect all matching pairs.

Comment: The **** in the pattern represents, an empty place for any number :-)

Comment: You say that this is "Similar to Longest Palindromic Subsequence", but I think it actually just *is* the longest palindromic subsequence problem!

Comment: @Jerry link for code : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-12-longest-palindromic-subsequence/

Comment: Re: "@ruakh I need your upvote :-)": Sorry, but I don't think this answer merits one. I've already indicated that I think the first sentence is not quite right; and the whole rest of the answer is very difficult to read (poor punctuation and formatting, bizarre notations, etc.). I would ask you to improve it, but the question is a duplicate that simply screams "please do my homework for me", so I don't actually *want* you to improve it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working algorithm I wrote in R. While this works it's overly verbose because I'm tired.

I can come back tomorrow and make it shorter if you need, but hopefully you can just see the logic and then make your own version in whatever language.

```
# Example data
num_list <- c(0,1,2,0,3,8,3,2,9,1,9)

# Declare empty vector for later
tmp <- numeric()

# Find out which numbers can be ruled out based on frequency
cnt <- as.data.frame(table(num_list))

# Keep pairs, fix data classes
for(i in unique(cnt$num_list)){
  if(cnt$Freq[cnt$num_list==i] == 2){
    tmp <- c(as.numeric(as.character(
      cnt$num_list[cnt$num_list == i])), tmp)    
  }  
}

num_list <- num_list[num_list%in%tmp]

# Figure out where the max (peak) number is, to cut the data 
peak <- numeric()
for(i in 1:(length(num_list)-1)){
  if(!is.na(num_list[i]) & num_list[i] == num_list[i+1]){
    peak <- num_list[i]
  }
}

# Apply nesting filter to first half of data
drop <- numeric()
for(i in 1:(length(num_list)-1)){
  if(!is.na(num_list[i]) & num_list[i] == peak){
    break
  } else if(!is.na(num_list[i]) & num_list[i] > num_list[i+1]){
    num_list[i+1] <- NA
  }
}

num_list <- num_list[!is.na(num_list)] 
num_list <- num_list[!num_list %in% 
                     unique(num_list)[table(num_list)==1]]

num_list.beg <- num_list[1:(max(which(num_list==peak)))]
num_list.end <- num_list[(max(which(num_list==peak))+1):length(num_list)]

# Apply nesting filter to second half of data     
for(i in 1:(length(num_list.end)-1)){
 if(!is.na(num_list.end[i]) & num_list.end[i] <= num_list.end[i+1]){
   num_list.end[i+1] <- NA
  }
}

num_list.end <- num_list.end[!is.na(num_list.end)]
num_list     <- c(num_list.beg, num_list.end)

# Sort them like you did in your desired output
sort(num_list)
```

> 1 1 2 2 3 3