# How to find longest palindrome

Tags: c++, palindrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Write a function that returns the longest palindrome in a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115001/write-a-function-that-returns-the-longest-palindrome-in-a-given-string)

I have a C++ assignment which wants me write a program that finds the longest palindrome in a given text. For example, the text is this: `asdqerderdiedasqwertunut`, my program should find `tunut` in the index of 19. However if input is changed into this `astunutsaderdiedasqwertunut`it should find `astunutsa` in the index of 0 instead of `tunut`in index of 22.

So, my problem is this. But I am a beginner at the subject, i know just string class, loops, ifs. It would be great if you could help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't even know where to start, perhaps you should go ask whoever set you the assignment.

Comment: Actually I am troubling in stage of forming an algorithm, so unfortunately I don't have any algorithm so far.

Comment: @MerveÇakır Start with an algorithm to decide if a given string is a palindrome.

Comment: @twain249 I am now able to find if a given string is a palindrome or not, but only if it is a word as we now it. In this case the text is something complex and palindrome should be inside somewhere in the text.

Comment: @MerveÇakır can you post that code. The point of SO is to help find whats wrong with something, not write the algorithm for you.

Comment: My intention was not you to ask the code for me, a simple inspiration could work as it did now. Thanks for @dasblinkenlight for the help.

Comment: Also thanks @grc. That link is very useful. I couldn't find it when I searched for existing questions.

Comment: so I am supposed to do your homework for you so you can get an A. Then you will come interview with my company and fail every questions -- waste my time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is very simple:

- Write a function `is_palindrome(string)` that takes a string, and returns `true` if it is a palindrome and `false` if it is not
- With that function in hand, write two nested loops cutting out different substrings from the original string. Pass each substring to `is_palindrome(string)`, and pick the longest one among the strings returning `true`.

You can further optimize your program by examining longest substrings ahead of shorter ones. If you examine substrings from longest to shortest, you'll be able to return as soon as you find the first palindrome.

Comment: this will work but is very inefficient. There is an `O(n)` algorithm in the question that @grc linked to.

Comment: Thanks, actually that was the thing I was looking for.

Comment: @twain249 Questions marked with the "homework" tag are usually asking about slow, inefficient, easy to understand algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Dasblinkenlight's idea is pretty good, but it's faster this way:

A palindrome has either an even number of letters or odd, so you have two situations. Let's start with the even. You need to find two consecutive identical letters, and then check whether the immediately previous letter is identical to the next letter. The same in the other situation, except at first you only need one letter. I don't speak English that well, so I hope you understood. :)