# How can I optimize this code for finding a palindrome?

Tags: python, optimization

The code works, however, it is not efficient when inputs are very large. How can I optimize this?

Longest Palindromic Substring: Given a string `s`, return the longest palindromic substring in `s`.

```
def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
    ans = ""
    perm = ""
    for i in s:
        perm = ""
        for j in s:
            perm += j
            if perm == perm[::-1] and len(perm) > len(ans):
                ans = perm
        s = s[1:]
        
    return ans
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write a function that returns the longest palindrome in a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115001/write-a-function-that-returns-the-longest-palindrome-in-a-given-string)

Comment: See also [How to check for palindrome using Python logic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17331290/12345551)

Answer (score 0):

```
def palindrome(word):
    return word[::-1] == word:
```

Comment: The anecdote is cute, but please just link to the existing answer; don't make it a separate post here.  Also, the `if` is redundant.  Simply return the value of the Boolean expression.
`return word[::-1] == word` does the job in one statement.

Comment: Understood! Thanks